# I Tried To Add Booleans, But It Gave The Wrong Answer. Advent Of Code 2022, Day 4

Tags: python

So what I had to do for this challenge was parse through a text file, looks like this

```
1-6,7-9
10-11,11-11
```

And I had to check if one range contains each other. In the above, in the second pair, range 2 is fully contained in range 1. I had to check for stuff like that.
So I built this code.

```
with open("input4.txt") as f:
    text_array = f.read().split("\n")
    total = 0
    for i in text_array:
        parts = i.split(",")
        pair1 = parts[0].split("-")
        pair2 = parts[1].split("-")
        if (pair1[0] <= pair2[0] and pair1[1] >= pair2[1]) and (pair2[0] <= pair1[0] and pair2[1] >= pair1[1]):
          total += 1 

    print(total)
```

(Ignore the other print statements but the last one) And it gave me 596, which in the advent of code it says it is too high.

It gave me 596, and when put into the problem, it says it is too high. I am wondering if there are any cases that slid in or idk. I literally made custom input, and it gave the correct answer.  Does anyone know where did I go wrong?

Comment: You're comparing strings. Start your interpreter, enter `"9" < "10"`, and think about the result.

Comment: Hi, Riyan, So aims to answer all questions, in the wider way possible.
So, next time, try avoiding references that are not needed in the title (except the question excludes problem for other code challenges -this is not the case).

(I've tried but I can't) I'd edit your post to exclude that, putting the reference to the code challenge in the end, in case someone is interested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Not sure but comparing strings may lead to issues when numbers are made of several digits.

```py
pair1 = [int(x) for x in  parts[0].split("-")]
pair2 = [int(x) for x in  parts[1].split("-")]
```

Comment: Yes of course. `int()` is just the function that converts a string to an integer. It can fail but here we assume that the string is well-formatted and don't try to catch any exception. I use the **list-comprehension** mechanism. "[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) provide a concise way to create lists" .

Answer (score -4):

Looks like the problem is in your "if".
maybe you can try this code

```
text_array = f.read().split("\n")
total = 0
for i in text_array:
parts = i.split(",")
pair1 = parts[0].split("-")
pair2 = parts[1].split("-")
if (pair1[0] <= pair2[0] and pair1[1] >= pair2[1]) or (pair2[0] <= pair1[0] and pair2[1] >= pair1[1]):
total += 1
```

Comment: Replace and with or will just make the final result even higher.